# How to configure WAMP to be RESTful?

Tags: php, apache, api, rest, wamp

I'm trying to write a RESTful API for my Android app. I am trying to write the server in PHP, and I'm trying to host it on a WAMP server. I want to be able to `GET, PULL, PUT,` and `DELETE`.
 In class, our professor showed us an example of how he configured his server, but he used MAMP (for Macintosh), which seems to have a different file hierarchy than WAMP.
He showed us that our `index.php` server file goes into this folder, and I'll use an `api` folder for the example:

```
  MAMP -> htdocs -> api -> index
```

When I access the URL `localhost:8080/api/`, it should execute a particular `GET` request.

He also noted that we needed to enable `aliasing`.
So in the `MAMP -> conf -> httpd.conf`, we added  `Alias /quotes "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/index.php"`.

But, I'm unable to get this work with my WAMP server. I noticed that it is a bit different in file heirarchy. To access the `htdocs` and `conf` folder I have to do the following:
`WAMP->bin->apache->Apache2.4.4->htdocs`
`WAMP->bin->apache->Apache2.4.4->conf`

and I modified my `conf` file as such:
`Alias /quotes "/WAMP/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/htdocs/api/index.php"`

So do I configure the WAMP differently? Do I need to move the `conf` and `htdocs` folders into the root `WAMP` folder? I tried putting my api into the `WAMP->www` directory, but it wouldn't work for the following `GET` request.

`//GET       /api/2                 Gets someone based on primary key`

I tried  looking at many tutorials, and I found many that were great in explaining API's and how to code an API that handles requests, but I was unable to find one that shows how to configure the server and get that working.

Any help, explanations, links to resources would be helpful and very appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Did you setup WAMP on port 8080?  The default is 80.  Can you get t o http://localhost ?  And yes, your files should be in WAMP/www/api  your conf files need to stay in /bin/apache/Apache2.4.4.  You need configure your alias /quotes to  "C:WAMP\www\api" or wherever your web files are located.  See this article on [WAMP Alias'](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-aliases-on-your-wamp-server/)

Comment: Yes @Grasshopper, it is configured for port 8080, and yes, I have developed some working Web Apps with my WAMP server on localhost:8080. It's good to know that, that's where my server goes. I thought as much, but I just wanted to make sure. Thank you for the article, it looks promising. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I needed to put my `api` folder in the `c:/wamp/www` folder.
My `httpd.conf` was in the right spot. (`/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf`), but my line for aliasing was incorrect, it should have been:
`Alias /quotes "c:/wamp/www/api/index.php"`

The URL i needed to navigate was:
`http://localhost:8080/quotes` (*Because I aliased it.*)

And of course, I needed to restart my WAMP server once I modified the `httpd.conf` file.